# Wordcloud for only emojis

Tags: python, matplotlib, nlp, word-cloud

I have a text full of emojis.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from wordcloud import WordCloud
wordcloud = WordCloud().generate(text)
plt.imshow(wordcloud)
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

when i try to get a wordcloud for those emojis like the code above, it returns an error like this:

```
ValueError: We need at least 1 word to plot a word cloud, got 0.
```

I think the wordcloud library is unable to read emojis.
I want to get an output like this(with emojis of course):

[image: wordcloud]

Anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you try this: https://amueller.github.io/word_cloud/auto_examples/emoji.html

Comment: i did and got a plot like this:

https://ibb.co/sJc4hqD

i looked into it and saw that in Windows, encoding is pretty problematic

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: what do you have in `text` ? You could add example in question (not in comment)

Comment: your image can mean it uses font which don't have emojis.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a wordcloud of emojis, you first have to get a font that supports emojis such as [Symbola](https://dn-works.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/UFAS-Fonts/Symbola.zip) and place the `otf` or `ttf` file within your working directory.

Then you need to install the required library:

```
pip install emojis matplotlib wordcloud
```

After that you can use this code to create a Wordcloud containing emojis.

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud
from collections import Counter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import emojis

class EmojiCloud:
    def __init__(self, font_path='Symbola.otf'):
        self.font_path = font_path
        self.word_cloud = self.initialize_wordcloud()
        self.emoji_probability = None

        
    def initialize_wordcloud(self):
        return WordCloud(font_path=self.font_path,
                               width=2000,
                               height=1000,
                               background_color='white',
                               random_state=42,
                               collocations=False)

    
    def color_func(self, word, font_size, position, orientation, random_state=None,
                   **kwargs):
        hue_saturation = '42, 88%'

        current_emoji_probability = self.emoji_probability[word]
        if current_emoji_probability >= 0.10:
            opacity = 50
        else:
            opacity = 75 - current_emoji_probability/0.2 * 5
        return f"hsl({hue_saturation},{opacity}%)"

    def generate(self, text):
        emoji_frequencies = Counter(emojis.iter(text))
        total_count = sum(emoji_frequencies.values())
        
        self.emoji_probability = {emoji: count/total_count for emoji, count in emoji_frequencies.items()}
        wc = self.word_cloud.generate_from_frequencies(emoji_frequencies)
        
        plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
        plt.imshow(wc.recolor(color_func=self.color_func, random_state=42))
        plt.axis("off")
```

This code can be used as follow:

```
text = 'a lot of emojis '

emoji_cloud = EmojiCloud(font_path='./Symbola.otf')
emoji_cloud.generate(text)
```

This will plot the following result:
[image]